# Batch, hybrid syntax with Gow, SCP in a for loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, scp

I'm making this little script with batch, it's about getting logs from multiple webservers (apache), and I'm on an IIS server with gow installed (permit me to use Linux cmd).

In my code I have this for loop:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

for /L %%X in (0,1,%end%) do (
    echo scp -l Brooze -pw Brooze !ip_vector[%%X]!:!mypathLogLX_cedre! !mypathLogLX_stock!\!mysite!\access_log
)
```

This works, but when I remove the `echo` and just do the `scp`, it works in the first iteration of my for loop, but not in the second, because in the second iteration, all my variables like that: `!var!`, which does not seem to be working.

Comment: I don't see any of those variables defined.  It should not even work once!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, scp is a batch script (scp.bat). So you would need to use

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

for /L %%X in (0,1,%end%) do (
  call scp -l Brooze -pw Brooze !ip_vector[%%X]!:!mypathLogLX_cedre! !mypathLogLX_stock!\!mysite!\access_log
)
```

The reason why your original code (without CALL) fails on the 2nd iteration and beyond is because when scp.bat exits, it terminates the batch file context, so delayed expansion is no longer enabled. But the FOR /L command continues to completion.